# How the constructor is working within another class

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, static, default-constructor

here is a use of static class object inside another class along with a scope resoution operator now i'm not sure whether the static object or the scope resolution operator is the reason that the constuctor from a different class is also invoked.
the code is:

```
class A
{
    public:
        A()
        {
            cout<<"A's constructor"<<endl;
        }
};
class B
{
    static A a;
    public:
        B()
        {
            cout<<"B's constructor";
        }
        static A get()
        {
            return a;
        }
};
A B :: a;
```

thus along with the main part

```
int main()
{
    B b;

    A a1=b.get();

    A a2=b.get();

    A a3=b.get();

}
```

And here is the output:

```
A's constructor
B's constructor
```

Another query is that whether the get function is actually doing anything?

Comment: What's the part that confuses you exactly? Static initialization happens before entering `main`, which initializes `B::A` (calling the ctor of `A`), it then enters main, and constructs `B b`. The rest of the `A` objects (a1, a2 and a3) call the copy constructor.

Comment: there is no inheritance in your code. The question is rather unclear

Comment: what other output did you expect and why?

Answer (score 1):

Define one more constructor, the copy constructor, in the class A. For example

```
A( const A & ) { cout << "A's copy constructor" << endl; }
```

and you will get the following output

```
A's constructor
B's constructor
A's copy constructor
A's copy constructor
A's copy constructor
```

That is the first constructor is called to create the static object of the class A die to its definition

```
A B :: a;
```

Then within main there is created an object of the type B. And ion these statements

```
A a1=b.get();

A a2=b.get();

A a3=b.get();
```

there are created three object of the type A using the copy constructor.

Comment: can you add a little more about the A B:: a; ??